# Unable to resolve Sql Server Management studio error "Cannot find one or more components"

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015

I am using Windows 8. Recently I installed Visual Studio 2015. I was having SQL Server Management studio 2012. After uninstalling Visual studio 2012 I manually deleted some of the files from Control Panel and this created the problem that whenever I am opening SQL Server management studio it says "Cannot find one or more component". I reinstalled SQL server management studio but it didn't get fixed. To solve this problem I was searching over the internet and I found someone's post

"Uninstall the Visual Studio 2010 Shell, this was done by downloading the installer.

Once downloaded, run the installer and remove the VS2010 Shell component. Once done, run the SQL 2014 Management Studio installer or do a repair on your existing installation, this will itself reinstall the VS2010 Shell components.

Then it opened for me."

As now I am using VS 2015 so I was searching for Visual studio 2015 shell. But I couldn't find it anywhere. 
Want to know any alternative or URL where I can get VS 2015 shell from.